# In Salesforce Marketing Cloud, is it possible to separate BCC/CC Bounces and opens from the intended subscriber?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, journeybuilder, deliverability, tracking

I have a SFMC journey on which I CC a personalization string (email in DE). I want to see if it's possible to separate the interaction of the 'to' line recipient from the actions of the 'CC' individual.

I know it didn't use to be a possibility but am hoping that might have changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the email engagement is linked to a specific subscriber (and this subscriber is defined as a combination of an email address and subscriber/contact key) you will not be able to distinguish engagement from an actual subscriber and cc/bcc recipient (as the latter are not seen as an actual subscriber).

The technical explanation is, that the tracking pixel and link tracking are not unique for to/cc/bcc recipients, so each of these email addresses will get an email where e.g. your main CTA is tracked as: https://click.e.example.com/?qs=5472tyfugu3f73t - not being distinguishable from one another.

Comment: That is what I assumed, but didn’t know if someone had developed a workaround. I supposed you send the same copy to a separate population. Thank you @Lukas !